# Extracting relationships out of text

Tags: stanford-nlp

That is one example text:

> Last year Jaap van der Meer, TAUS’s founder and director, wrote a provocative blogpost entitled “The Future Does Not Need Translators”, arguing that the quality of MT will keep improving, and that for many applications less-than-perfect translation will be good enough.

Now I'd like to learn that:

```
PERSON(Jaap van der Meer) is JOB(founder and director) of ORGANISATION (TAUS)
```

What I get from Standford OpenIE and OpenIE is something like:

```
TAUS    has     founder
Jaap van der Meer       wrote   blogpost
```

In general, I'd like to extract the job positions / business relationships between organisations and organisations or people and organisation out of free text like news articles etc.

How can I get this working with Stanford OpenIE?
Is there a better tool to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try using the KBPAnnotator.  This will extract (person, title, job title) relations and (person, organization, works_for) relations among others.

Example command:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,regexner,parse,mention,entitymentions,coref,kbp -file example.txt -outputFormat text
```